Power BI Paginated Report - Upto monthly parameter
I require your guidance for my needs.
I want to update a parameter based on month which currently selects a month, whereas I want it to behave in a way that if we select May, it should be able to select all the months leading upto May, i.e. January, February, March, April, and May.
Currently I've a month parameter which selects one month in the month dropdown or selects all if we click the selects all button (as shown in the img). I want to upgrade these parameter so, that it selects all the month leading upto and including the selected month.
Hope you all can get what I need.
Thank you in advance.
I've tried to create a calculated column which assign MonthIndex to their respective month and a measure which determine the highest MonthIndex of the months that are currently selected by the Cal Month in the powerbi report.

May be the Issue is small i think.
you should just select the months by ctrl + click and it will select multiple months.

You can do that, but that's not what the OP is asking for.
